# Свой шаблон в SuggestView - Яндекс карта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yandex-maps-api

Как создавать свой шаблон в SuggestView я понял, но как вывести данные от SuggestView в шаблоне - я так и не понял.

Код suggestview:

```
const suggestLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass('<div>вот здесь нужно вывести список с результатами от SuggestView</div>')

_this.suggest = new ymaps.SuggestView('element', {
  layout: suggestLayout
})
```

Все это дело происходит внутри Vue компонента. Пробовал внутри `createClass('{% properties %}')` - ничего не отдает.